# mongo convert or $rename, $set, $unset a lat lon into 2dsphere Point coordinates array

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

is there any $rename o $set $unset sequence to convert a subdocument

```
"loc" : {"lon" : x.0 , "lat" : y.0 }
```

into a 2dsphere "compliant" subdocument that includes the type and coordinates in an array

```
"loc: " {"type": "Point", "coordinates" [ x.0, y.0]
```

using only the mongo shell. (aka without writing an external script)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to currently `update` a field by manipulating the existing value of that field, but you can do the following:

```
db.collection.find().forEach(function(doc){
var location = {"type":"Point","coordinates":[doc.loc.lon,doc.loc.lat]};
db.collection.update({"_id":doc._id},{$set:{"loc":location}});
})
```

Basically, if we want to `update` a field with a new value that is `derived` from it's old value, we need to get hold of that old value first, then `modify` it and `update` the field with the new value.
`MongoDB` query framework **limits** us from doing these operations in a single query.

Comment: to finish off this answer, place only that script into a file, then run `mongo db nameoffile.js`   as found in http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/write-scripts-for-the-mongo-shell/